# Opening tango generated PLY's on a computer

Tags: google-project-tango

Im using RTAB-Map to generate .PLY Meshes that I can open on my computer. However, after importing both 3d Builder and Meshlab give me a file not supported error. What is different about Tango generated .PLY's? How can i open these on a computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to just open the file with notepad++ and see where the missmatch is laying.
a ply file is just a header and then all points + faces in the body

Here a header from a file I created myself:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment Author: MAG
obj_info Generated by CloudColorator!
element vertex 587816
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
element face 1221509
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
```

The body:
In the next line follow all points

```
-3.24198 1.03606 1.14794 118 123 116 -0.0810083 -0.0129849 -0.996629
```

After all points come the vertieces

```
3 11585 2357 2362
```

The three at the beginning says one face includes three vertices.

A lot of programs are only able to read faces with three vertices, this could be an issue.
I use cloudcompare to visualize my meshes.